# How to call wordpress plugin in pages without shortcode?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress, I would like to know how to call wordpress plugin without shortcode in pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For calling plugin on page you have to use shortcode, and if you don't want to use shortcode than add the relevant plugin code to functions.php file.

Comment: In functions.php file you can add code of plugin inside a function and you can use that function according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Open the page in the admin section and in editor of the page add your short code then update it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, right now i am trying to do it without short code, Is there any way to do it using functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your plugins functions without shortcode, just call the function. If the plugin is activated and the function exist it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, where should i call function? in page or somewhere else